# C: conflicting types error

Tags: c, list, struct, type-conversion

I want to check a linked List of Elements holding an Integer each, if a value is already inside.

```
struct ListenElement{
    int wert;
    struct ListenElement *nachfolger;
};

struct ListenAnfang{
    struct ListenElement *anfang;
};

struct ListenAnfang LA;

bool ckeckForInt(int value){
    if (LA.anfang == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    return checkCurrent(LA.anfang, value);
}

bool checkCurrent(struct ListenElement* check, int value){
    if (check->wert == value){
        return true;
    }
    else if (check->nachfolger != NULL){
        return checkCurrent(check->nachfolger, value);
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Im getting a conflicting types for the checkCurrent Method, but can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is missing the function declaration.
In C, you need to declare the function, exactly as it is.

```
struct ListenElement{
    int wert;
    struct ListenElement *nachfolger;
};

struct ListenAnfang{
    struct ListenElement *anfang;
};

struct ListenAnfang LA;

//The function declaration !
bool checkCurrent(struct ListenElement* check, int value);

bool ckeckForInt(int value){
    if (LA.anfang == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    return checkCurrent(LA.anfang, value);
}

bool checkCurrent(struct ListenElement* check, int value){
    if (check->wert == value){
        return true;
    }
    else if (check->nachfolger != NULL){
        return checkCurrent(check->nachfolger, value);
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`checkCurrent()` is used *before* it is declared, or defined, which results in an implicit function declaration being generated with a return type of `int` (which is not the same as the definition of the function which has return type `bool`). Add a declaration for `checkCurrent()` prior to its first use:

```
bool checkCurrent(struct ListenElement* check, int value);

bool ckeckForInt(int value){
    if (LA.anfang == NULL){
        return false; /* Changed '0' to 'false'. */
    }
    return checkCurrent(LA.anfang, value);
}
```

or move its definition prior to `checkForInt()`.